# Access query SUM results (with conditions) from a multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, subquery

On MS-Access datebase I've created two tables:

**table1:**

| id | joinKey | cMaterialPrice | sMaterialPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41 | 7 | 11 |
| 2 | 43 | 18 | 44 |
| 3 | 42 | 12 | 0 |
| 4 | 43 | 15 |  |
| 5 | 41 |  |  |
| 6 | 43 | 7 | 11 |

**table2:**

| id | joinKey | cLabourPrice | sLabourPrice | method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41 | 4 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 42 | 2 | 44 | 1 |
| 3 | 43 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 43 | 12 |  | 2 |
| 5 | 42 |  |  | 1 |
| 6 | 42 | 7 | 11 | 1 |
| 7 | 41 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

Basing on joinKey I want to return for each jointKey results for:

- SUM of cMaterialPrice
- SUM of cMaterialPrice
- SUM of cLabourPrice if method =1
- SUM of cLabourPrice if method =2
- SUM of sLabourPrice if method =1
- SUM of sLabourPrice if method =2

I can do this with a query:

> SELECT  
> [table1].[joinKey], 
> SUM([table1].[cMaterialPrice]) AS [CMP],  
> SUM([table1].[sMaterialPrice]) AS [SMP],
>
> (SELECT SUM([table2].[cLabourPrice])
> FROM  [table2]
> WHERE [table1].[joinKey] = [table2].[joinKey] AND [table2].[method] = 1
> ) AS [CLP1],
>
> (SELECT SUM([table2].[cLabourPrice])
> FROM  [table2]
> WHERE [table1].[joinKey] = [table2].[joinKey] AND [table2].[method] = 2
> ) AS [CLP2],
>
> (SELECT SUM([table2].[sLabourPrice])
> FROM  [table2]
> WHERE [table1].[joinKey] = [table2].[joinKey] AND [table2].[method] = 1
> ) AS [SLP1],
>
> (SELECT SUM([table2].[sLabourPrice])
> FROM  [table2]
> WHERE [table1].[joinKey] = [table2].[joinKey] AND [table2].[method] = 2
> ) AS [SLP2]
>
> FROM
> [table1]
>
> GROUP BY
> [table1].[joinKey]

ok, it working fine but when I will have i.e. 5 kind of methods the code will be very long and won't work effectively.

the expected result of the query is: 
[image]

**Does anybody know a way for modifying the query for more flexible ?** 
(I'd like to avoid VBA in this case)

Comment: What happens if you include all sums and add a `GROUP BY method`

Comment: Your expected outcome doesn't make sense to me if your goal is not to have a lot of code for 5 kinds of methods. Instead of having a never0ending set of columns - (two for each method) - it's better to add a method column and group by it along with the join key.

Answer (score 0):

Simple query that I think gives you what you want by adding the GROUP BY and including all SUMS in the same query

I've used `LEFT JOINs` in these examples - but it's possible you just want the matches where joinkey is in both tables. In that case replace with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Table1.joinKey, Table2.method, 
    Sum(cMaterialPrice) AS CMP, Sum(sMaterialPrice) AS SMP, 
    Sum(cLabourPrice) AS CLP, Sum(sLabourPrice) AS SLP
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.joinKey = Table2.joinKey
GROUP BY Table1.joinKey, Table2.method;
```

Results in:

[image: Results]

Or if you want the methods grouped regardless of join key, you can eliminate the `GROUP BY joinkey`

```
SELECT method, Sum(cMaterialPrice) AS CMP, Sum(sMaterialPrice) AS SMP, Sum(cLabourPrice) AS CLP, Sum(sLabourPrice) AS SLP
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.joinKey = Table2.joinKey
GROUP BY method;
```

Which gives you this:

[image: No Joinkey grouped]

Comment: Thank You dbmitch,  but unfortunately It works incorrectly in some rows and I see problem when the same JoinKey has different method (two or more rows with the same JoinKey in result)  - I edited my orginal post by adding filed no 7 to table2. Anyway I will try to work for modify your code

Comment: Best to include your expected results in your question

Comment: ok, is added to the orginal post.